# Docker compose : error copying nginx.conf fron nginx image

Tags: nginx, docker-compose, nginx-config

I am using a `docker-compose.yml` in which I describe 2 services , one for frontend app and the second one is for backend :

```
version: '2'
services:
  cdl-front:
    build: cdl-web/.
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    depends_on:
        - cdl-rest
  cdl-rest:
    build: cdl-rest/.
    ports:
      - "7777:7777"
```

When I try to launch my docker-compose configuration using IntelliJ IDEA configured with Docker plugin I get this error :

> ERROR: Service 'cdl-front' failed to build: COPY failed: stat
>   /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder939775883/nginx.conf: no such file
>   or directory Failed to deploy 'Compose: docker-compose.yml':
>   `docker-compose` process finished with exit code 1
>   Below is my 2 dockerfiles describing the 2 services :

cdl-front contain this `dockerfile` :

```
FROM nginx
WORKDIR .
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
COPY cdl-frontend/cdl /usr/share/nginx/html
```

cdl-rest contain this `dockerfile`

```
# Start with a base image containing Java runtime
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine

# Add Maintainer Info
LABEL maintainer="ghassen1khalil@gmail.com"

# Add a volume pointing to /tmp
VOLUME /tmp

# Make port 8080 available to the world outside this container
EXPOSE 9091

# The application's jar file
ARG JAR_FILE=target/cdl-rest-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar

# Add the application's jar to the container
ADD ${JAR_FILE} cdl-rest.jar

# Run the jar file
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8","-jar","/cdl-rest.jar"]
CMD ["--env=prod"]
```

Comment: What the file/directory structure in the directory containing Dockerfile?

Comment: I have 2 dockerfiles and a docker-compose on the root, you can see this link for the structure https://pastebin.com/3CMLaiwX

Comment: Where is in the structure `nginx.conf` placed? And when you try to build it from shell using `docker-compose build` instead of IDEA plugin, does it work?

Comment: @michalhosna `nginx.conf` is packed within the official nginx image I think .. I'm not overriding it.  When I try to build it from shell I get the same error : `Service 'cdl-front' failed to build: COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder045278574/nginx.conf: no such file or directory`

Comment: @ghassen If you are not overriding it, what are you doing with `COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf`. That should override `nginx.conf` with your custom `nginx.conf`

Comment: @michalhosna as I am starting Docker I didn't knew that `COPY` do this ! Now I remved it and it works fine. Thank you anyway :)

Comment: Great! :-). Dockerfile has pretty good reference where you can read more, about what directives in Dockerfile actually do. https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/